# docker build : getting-started tutorial => Certificate error

Tags: docker, ssl

I'm having troubles with the getting started tutorial of docs.docker.com :
https://docs.docker.com/get-started/02_our_app/

When i execute the following command :
docker build -t getting-started .

I get the following errors :

```
     > [2/5] RUN apk add --no-cache python2 g++ make:
    #5 0.412 fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
    #5 0.551 139899692677960:error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c:1914:
    #5 0.552 WARNING: Ignoring https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/main: Permission denied
    #5 0.552 fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
    #5 0.603 139899692677960:error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c:1914:
    #5 0.604 WARNING: Ignoring https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/community: Permission denied
    #5 0.604 ERROR: unable to select packages:
    #5 0.605   g++ (no such package):
    #5 0.605     required by: world[g++]
    #5 0.605   make (no such package):
    #5 0.605     required by: world[make]
    #5 0.605   python2 (no such package):
    #5 0.605     required by: world[python2]
    ------
    executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apk add --no-cache python2 g++ make]: exit code: 3
```

I'm on Windows 10 V1909 and i downloaded WSL 2 like specified in the tutorial.

EDIT :
Like Hans Kilian answered, it was a VPN problem...

Comment: It works when I try. Are you in an environment where a proxy intercepts encrypted traffic and re-encrypts it with it's own certificate that you need to trust?

Comment: Indeed... i was behind my company VPN. I tried to disable it and retry ... and it works ! I'm happy but i wanna cry :(. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Like Hans Kilian answered, it was a VPN problem...

Be careful if you are behind a proxy.